# Power Query clear cells in column with <4 characters

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Using Power Query to clean data set. I am trying to clear the cells in a column with 4 or less characters, leaving the remaining cells of the column (>4 characters).

I have googled every possible way to explain my intent without finding a suitable solution.

Comment: Did either of these two answers work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for that answer mark it as solving the issue

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQyVorVAdMmcIYpgmWmFBsLAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,each [Column1],each if Text.Length([Column1]) > 4 then [Column1] else null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: This works if each cell is individually text, but not if it is numerical.  So ="12345 works but not =12345

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using transform instead of replace. Neither is better

```
let Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQyVorVAdMmcIYpgmWmFBsLAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
Trim = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Column1", each if Text.Length(Text.From(_)??"") <5 then null else _ }})
in  Trim
```

Comment: Slick use of null coalescing operator to avoid errors